# Xamarin support for early version of Sitecore

Tags: xamarin

We are working on for creating mobile app for one of the client and we have started evaluating it. It is on sitecore 7.0. We ant to use Xamarin. Does Xamarin supports this version of Sitecore.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the answer provided above except for the part that you need a Xamarin license. Xamarin is now free and is a built-in installation available for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (or you can also download for free Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013).

Working with Xamarin and Sitecore might seem a bit tricky for the first time. You may find some useful information in this blog post: [Getting started with Xamarin and Sitecore Mobile SDK](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2016/10/Getting-started-with-Sitecore-Mobile-SDK-and-Xamarin.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Mobile SDK for Xamarin supports Sitecore starts from the Sitecore CMS 6.6 SP1  version. Additionally, you need to install Sitecore Item Web API module v1.2 or later on the Sitecore instance.

Also For iOS and Android application development using the Xamarin platform, you also need:

- Xamarin Studio 5.5.4 or later installed
- A Xamarin license

You can get more information on following. https://doc.sitecore.net/mobile_sdk_for_xamarin/web_api_10/mobile_sdk_installation_and_configuration/requirements_for_the_sitecore_mobile_sdk

For more documentation, please look at https://doc.sitecore.net/mobile_sdk_for_xamarin